# Probability puzzle about crossing lights – what is wrong with my reasoning?

Tags: probability

> Calvin has to cross several signals when he walks from his home to
>   school. Each of these signals operate independently. They alternate
>   every 80 seconds between green light and red light.At each signal,
>   there is a counter display that tells him how long it will be before
>   the current signal light changes. Calvin has a magic wand which lets
>   him turn a signal from red to green instantaneously. However, this
>   wand comes with limited battery life, so he can use it only for a
>   specified number of times.
>
> If the total number of signals is 2 and Calvin can use his magic
>   wand only once, then what is the expected waiting time at the signals
>   when Calvin optimally walks from his home to school?

I was convinced that I had the right solution, but apparently I didn't but I cannot see what is wrong with my reasoning.

My solution is as follows: Each light, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have uniformly distributed waiting times in $[0, 80]$. Basically, he has to make a decision at the first light. At the second light, he always uses the wand if it is available. I assume that he has to pick some optimal waiting time $x \in [0, 80]$ at the first light such that if $Y_1 > x$, he uses the wand. In that case, the waiting time at the first light becomes $0$.

Using this reasoning, the total expected time is
$$
\mathbb E[Y_1 1_{\lbrace Y_1 \leq x \rbrace} + Y_2 1_{\lbrace Y_1 > x \rbrace}]  = \\ 
\mathbb E[Y_1 1_{\lbrace Y_1 \leq x \rbrace}] + \mathbb E[Y_2]\mathbb P(Y_1 > x )
$$
This becomes
$$
\int^x_0 \frac{1}{80}u du + 40 \frac{80-x}{80} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x^2}{80} + 80 -x \right)
$$
Then differentiating, setting to $0$, solving for $x$ and plugging it back into the expectation gives me $30$ as the answer. I have been told that this is incorrect.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: I think one problem is that the waiting times are NOT uniformly distributed.  The waiting time $0$ has half the weight, with the other half being uniform over $(0,80).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without integration . . .

Let $x$ be the cutoff for using the wand on the first light (if it's red and the waiting time is at least $x$, use the wand).

Let $e$ be the expected waiting time for a fixed value of $x$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;e&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\left(
\left(\frac{80-x}{80}\right)\left(0+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)40\right)+
\left(\frac{x}{80}\right)\left(\frac{x}{2} + 0\right)
\right)
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{320}x^2-\frac{1}{8}x+10\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
$e$ is mimimized when $x=20$, giving an expected waiting time, in seconds, of ${\large{\frac{35}{4}}}=8.75$.

Explanation:

There's no waiting time if the first light is green, since the wand would be used if needed for the second light. That accounts for the global factor of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Assuming the first light is red, there are two cases . . .

Case ($1$): The wand gets used on the first light.

The probability that case ($1$) occurs is
$${\large{\frac{80-x}{80}}}$$
If case ($1$) occurs, there is no waiting time at light $1$ (thanks to the wand), and the expected waiting time at light $2$ is
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)40$$
hence the expected waiting time, given that case ($1$) occurs is
$$0+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)40$$
Case ($2$): The wand doesn't get used on the first light.

The probability that case ($2$) occurs is
$${\large{\frac{x}{80}}}$$
If case ($2$) occurs, there is no waiting time at light $2$ (thanks to the wand), and the expected waiting time at light $1$ is
$$\frac{x}{2}$$
hence the expected waiting time, given that case ($2$) occurs is
$$\frac{x}{2} + 0$$